# Modifying a local variable in Javascript every time the function is called

Tags: javascript

I want to increment the value of `i` everytime I call `myFunction()`. As you can see, every time the value of `i` gets initialized to `0`. So the result will always be zero. How to ensure that `i` remains a local variable and get the increment? How can this be done with the concept of closures?

```
function myFunction(){
    var i = 0;
    console.log(i);
    i++ 
};
myFunction();
myFunction();
myFunction();
myFunction(); // Result must be 3
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A little modification on @Carlo's answer. This keeps `myFunction` in the current scope.

```
var myFunction = (function() {
  var i = 0;
  return function (){
    console.log(i);
    i++;
  };
})();
```

Example:

```
myFunction(); // logs 0
myFunction(); // logs 1
myFunction(); // logs 2
myFunction(); // logs 3
```

Comment: Can this be done using the concept of closures? @A1rPun

Comment: @VishnuPaspunoor Actually `myFunction` is already a [closure](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures) here.

Answer (score 3):

Short answer: take the variable out of the scope.

```
(function() {
  var i = 0;
  myFunction = function (){
    console.log(i);
    i++ 
  };
})()

myFunction();
myFunction();
myFunction();
myFunction();
```

Using a wider scope function will prevent your variable from going global.

Comment: in fact that's burying it in a local / deeper scope, otherwise a closure.+1

Answer (score 0):

Put the variable in the global scope:

```
var i = 0;
function myFunction(){
    console.log(i);
    i++ 
};
myFunction();
myFunction();
myFunction();
myFunction(); // Result will be 3
```

Answer (score 0):

As others have suggested, taking the variable out of the function's scope is the answer. An alternative is to set the variable as a property of the function.

```
function myFunction() {

    if (typeof myFunction.i !== "number") {
        myFunction.i = 0;
    }

    console.log(myFunction.i);
    myFunction.i += 1;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function myFunction() {
    console.log(i);
    myFunction.i++
};
myFunction.i = 0;

myFunction();
myFunction();
myFunction();
myFunction(); // Result must be 3
```